# Average difference in days between the values within a column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'm having such a datafrmae in Python Pandas:
[image]

The "delivered_at" column is datetime while started_week is object column. I'm wondering, how can I using groupby() function will be able to receive the aggregation for a week for an average difference in days between the values in "delivered_at" column? Something like that:

```
started_week   avg_delivered
 2013-W03          7
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be

```
df.groupby('started_week').delivered_at.apply(lambda x: x.diff().mean())

started_week
2013-W03   7 days
Name: delivered_at, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```